# Do I need multiple exports from Game Maker to support Windows versions above 7?

Tags: game-maker, windows, compatibility

I just created a game. At the time of exporting it, I targeted windows.

[image]

I use windows 7 on my computer. Obviously the game is compatible with windows 7, but I do not know if it is also compatible with windows 8 and 10, because just below appears windows 8.

[image]

I intend to launch the game on steam, and even if it was not, it is very important for me not to frustrate anyone.

My question is whether I will have to create multiple executables for different versions of windows, or if selecting the windows option, the game will work for windows 7, 8, 10 and XP.

I looked it up on the developer's website, but it did not help. => https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/000_using%20gamemaker/009_distributing%20your%20game.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option creates a Windows executable application (.exe)
Those options related to Windows 8 creates an app similar to those available in the Microsoft Store. They are compiled in a different way and need of a special SDK to be created.

Comment: Ok. Could you tell me if it works for windows XP too?

Comment: Why would you want to support Windows XP anyhow?

Comment: From what I've researched, almost 10% of the world's computers have this operating system. It's a good audience, I wonder if it's compatible.

Comment: I guess for winXP if you create your app as an installer like you did here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/167032/shortcut-not-found-installing-game-created-in-gamemaker it would work but the PC needs a minimum of graphics capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

I believe windows includes all the versions of windows, Windows 8 build is [for functions specific to the windows 8 platform](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/windows8/index.html)