# Shortcut Not Found (installing game created in GameMaker)

Tags: game-maker, installer

I tested the game I created on 4 computers (ALL Windows 7) and had the following problem at installation time.

The shortcut created by the installer itself came like this:

[image]

When I click the following message appears:

[image]

Clicking in search appears this:

[image]

By clicking the application Bet on Man the shortcut would work correctly. However, not that the players have that task.

Comment: If you right-click the shortcut and choose "properties" there should be a section there, in one of the tabs, that shows you the path the shortcut is _attempting_ to point to. This likely differs from "Usuarios/Oczul/Bet on Man/Bet on Man.exe" -- it would be useful to know what path the shortcut's trying to use. It _sounds_ like it thinks the name of the executable is literally "${BET ON MAN}.exe" which sounds like a problem in the substitution of some variable somewhere.

Comment: Why don't you use single executable? I don't see any reason to use installer.

Comment: @Josh How could I rename the generated executable? I tried to change product and display name. Unsuccessfully.

Comment: @Dmi7ry I'd like to do this, but I do not know how.

Comment: @Boneco Sinforoso When you click "Create Application" the file save dialog lets you choose the type of the file Game maker will create. There you select "single runtime executable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of **Dmi7ry** and **Juanpa** who commented on my question, I was able to solve this problem.

When creating an application, just switch from **Windows NSIS Installer** to **Single runtime executable**:

[image]